# UnityException: Load is not allowed to be called from a MonoBehaviour constructor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am writing a script for Unity that is supposed to allow for other scripts to reference a list of assets. In this case, I want Dialogue to reference audio clips listed in MyAssets. The problem is in how I'm instantiating in MyAssets. I understand that I am supposed to instantiate in Start() or Awake() but I'm lost on how exactly to translate the code over.

Here are the parts of the scripts the exception points to:

```
public class Dialogue : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioClip[] voicesA = {
        MyAssets.instances.a0, 
    };
}
```

```
public class MyAssets : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static MyAssets _i;

    public static MyAssets instances {
    get {
        if (_i == null) _i = (Instantiate(Resources.Load("MyAssets")) as GameObject).GetComponent<MyAssets>();
        return instances;
        }
    }

    public AudioClip a0;
}
```

Here is the full exception:

```
UnityException: Load is not allowed to be called from a MonoBehaviour constructor (or instance field initializer), call it in Awake or Start instead. Called from MonoBehaviour 'Dialogue'.
See "Script Serialization" page in the Unity Manual for further details.
UnityEngine.ResourcesAPI.Load (System.String path, System.Type systemTypeInstance) (at <88d854ea2c91426ebc464f01cd71aa85>:0)
UnityEngine.Resources.Load (System.String path, System.Type systemTypeInstance) (at <88d854ea2c91426ebc464f01cd71aa85>:0)
UnityEngine.Resources.Load (System.String path) (at <88d854ea2c91426ebc464f01cd71aa85>:0)
MyAssets.get_instances () (at Assets/Scripts/MyAssets.cs:11)
Dialogue..ctor () (at Assets/Scripts/Dialogue.cs:18)
```

Comment: And did you read the page it said?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution from here is to only **access** the assets in `Awake` or `Start`. (You can still declare the load where it is currently.)

This can be done by only changing `Dialogue`.
Note how it only ever accesses `a0` in `Awake`.

```
public class Dialogue : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioClip[] voicesA
    {
        get => new AudioClip[] { MyAssets.instances.a0 };
    }

    void Awake() 
    {
        Debug.Log(voicesA);
    }
}
```

Aside from this, you'll also have to change the return statement in `MyAssets` to `return _i`. Otherwise you'll get a stackoverflow error.

Bonus point: take care in naming your variables. *"we should name a variable with the same care we do in naming a first-born child"* - Uncle Bob